# accessing values from an input filed in html + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/12p3d99m/1/)

I am looking at getting the values from an inpt form in html. for example I want to get the value that is entered in the `Cat name:` input form.

```
 <div id="admin-form">
        <form>
            Cat name:<input id="admin-cat-name" type="text" name="cat-name" placeholder="10" value="10"><br>
            Source:  <input id="admin-source" type="text" name="source"><br>
            Count:   <input id="admin-count" type="text" name="count">
            <button id="save-button" type="button">Save</button>
            <button id="cancel-button" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I am thinking along the lines of something like the below:

```
var form = $('form');
var form2 = $('form #admin-cat-name');

//alert(form)
console.log(form)
console.log(form2)  // i think this is an array that has the value that I want?
```

but I just can't quite get the value from the input form. Can anyone advise how I do this? And if I am going about it the right way?

Comment: You need: `var form2 = $('form #admin-cat-name').val();`

Comment: i found this works as well. `console.log(form2[0].value)`

Comment: You said you used jQuery. Why not stick with it?

Comment: propbably my lack of understanding. I was just play with the data object returned to get the values I want

Comment: Okay, does it work now?

Answer (score 3):

You are actually looking for [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Use the following code:

```
var form2 = $('form #admin-cat-name').val();
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `$("#admin-cat-name").val()`